# GitLab CI - Pipeline don't run when I push a tag

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

From what I understand, when I push a git tag in a Gitlab repo the pipeline is triggered and it starts his run. In my case whenever I push a git tag, the pipeline doesn't start and I don't know if there is a setting to activate this behavior or if I didn't understand this mechanism.

This is my `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```yaml
stages:
  - prepare
  - build_and_test
  - deploy

# If you are looking for a place where to add 'UNITY_LICENSE_FILE' and other secrets, please visit your project's gitlab page:
# settings > CI/CD > Variables instead
variables:
  BUILD_NAME: TestCIProject
  UNITY_ACTIVATION_FILE: ./unity3d.alf
  UNITY_VERSION: "2020.3.33f1"
  IMAGE: unityci/editor # https://hub.docker.com/r/unityci/editor
  IMAGE_VERSION: "1" # This will automatically use latest v0.x.x, see https://github.com/game-ci/docker/releases
  UNITY_DIR: $CI_PROJECT_DIR/TestCIProject # this needs to be an absolute path. Defaults to the root of your tree.
  # You can expose this in Unity via Application.version
  VERSION_NUMBER_VAR: $CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG-$CI_PIPELINE_ID-$CI_JOB_ID
  VERSION_BUILD_VAR: $CI_PIPELINE_IID

image: $IMAGE:$UNITY_VERSION-base-$IMAGE_VERSION

get-unity-version:
  image: alpine
  stage: prepare
  variables:
    GIT_DEPTH: 1
  script:
    - echo $CI_COMMIT_TAG
    - echo $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE
    - echo test
    - echo UNITY_VERSION=$(cat $UNITY_DIR/ProjectSettings/ProjectVersion.txt | grep "m_EditorVersion:.*" | awk '{ print $2}') | tee prepare.env
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: prepare.env

.unity_before_script: &unity_before_script
  before_script:
    - chmod +x ./ci/before_script.sh && ./ci/before_script.sh
  needs:
    - job: get-unity-version
      artifacts: true

.cache: &cache
  cache:
    key: "$CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE-$CI_PROJECT_NAME-$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG-$TEST_PLATFORM"
    paths:
      - $UNITY_DIR/Library/

.license: &license
  rules:
    - if: '$UNITY_LICENSE != null'
      when: always

.unity_defaults: &unity_defaults
  <<:
    - *unity_before_script
    - *cache
    - *license

# run this job when you need to request a license
# you may need to follow activation steps from documentation
get-activation-file:
  <<: *unity_before_script
  rules:
    - if: '$UNITY_LICENSE == null'
      when: manual
  stage: prepare
  script:
    - chmod +x ./ci/get_activation_file.sh && ./ci/get_activation_file.sh
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - $UNITY_ACTIVATION_FILE
    expire_in: 10 min # Expiring this as artifacts may contain sensitive data and should not be kept public

.test: &test
  stage: build_and_test
  <<: *unity_defaults
  script:
    - chmod +x ./ci/test.sh && ./ci/test.sh
  artifacts:
    when: always
    expire_in: 2 weeks
  # https://gitlab.com/gableroux/unity3d-gitlab-ci-example/-/issues/83
  # you may need to remove or replace these to fit your need if you are using your own runners
  tags:
    - gitlab-org
  coverage: /<Linecoverage>(.*?)</Linecoverage>/

# Tests without junit reporting results in GitLab
# test-playmode:
#   <<: *test
#   variables:
#     TEST_PLATFORM: playmode
#     TESTING_TYPE: NUNIT

# test-editmode:
#   <<: *test
#   variables:
#     TEST_PLATFORM: editmode
#     TESTING_TYPE: NUNIT

# uncomment the following blocks if you'd like to have junit reporting unity test results in gitlab
# We currently have the following issue which prevents it from working right now, but you can give
# a hand if you're interested in this feature:
# https://gitlab.com/gableroux/unity3d-gitlab-ci-example/-/issues/151

#.test-with-junit-reports: &test-with-junit-reports
#  stage: build_and_test
#  <<: *unity_defaults
#  script:
    # This could be made faster by adding these packages to base image or running in a separate job (and step)
    # We could use an image with these two depencencies only and only do the saxonb-xslt command on
    # previous job's artifacts
#    - apt-get update && apt-get install -y default-jre libsaxonb-java
#    - chmod +x ./ci/test.sh && ./ci/test.sh
#    - saxonb-xslt -s $UNITY_DIR/$TEST_PLATFORM-results.xml -xsl $CI_PROJECT_DIR/ci/nunit-transforms/nunit3-junit.xslt >$UNITY_DIR/$TEST_PLATFORM-junit-results.xml
#  artifacts:
#    when: always
#    paths:
    # This is exported to allow viewing the Coverage Report in detail if needed
#    - $UNITY_DIR/$TEST_PLATFORM-coverage/
#    reports:
#      junit:
#        - $UNITY_DIR/$TEST_PLATFORM-junit-results.xml
#        - "$UNITY_DIR/$TEST_PLATFORM-coverage/coverage.xml"
#    expire_in: 2 weeks
  # https://gitlab.com/gableroux/unity3d-gitlab-ci-example/-/issues/83
  # you may need to remove or replace these to fit your need if you are using your own runners
#  tags:
#    - gitlab-org
#  coverage: /<Linecoverage>(.*?)</Linecoverage>/

# test-playmode-with-junit-reports:
#   <<: *test-with-junit-reports
#   variables:
#     TEST_PLATFORM: playmode
#     TESTING_TYPE: JUNIT

# test-editmode-with-junit-reports:
#   <<: *test-with-junit-reports
#   variables:
#     TEST_PLATFORM: editmode
#     TESTING_TYPE: JUNIT

.build: &build
  stage: build_and_test
  <<: *unity_defaults
  script:
    - chmod +x ./ci/build.sh && ./ci/build.sh
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - $UNITY_DIR/Builds/
  # https://gitlab.com/gableroux/unity3d-gitlab-ci-example/-/issues/83
  # you may need to remove or replace these to fit your need if you are using your own runners
  tags:
    - gitlab-org
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG != null'

#build-StandaloneLinux64:
#  <<: *build
#  variables:
#    BUILD_TARGET: StandaloneLinux64

#build-StandaloneLinux64-il2cpp:
#  <<: *build
#  image: $IMAGE:$UNITY_VERSION-linux-il2cpp-$IMAGE_VERSION
#  variables:
#    BUILD_TARGET: StandaloneLinux64
#    SCRIPTING_BACKEND: IL2CPP

#build-StandaloneOSX:
#  <<: *build
#  image: $IMAGE:$UNITY_VERSION-mac-mono-$IMAGE_VERSION
#  variables:
#    BUILD_TARGET: StandaloneOSX

#Note: build target names changed in recent versions, use this for versions < 2017.2:
# build-StandaloneOSXUniversal:
#   <<: *build
#   variables:
#     BUILD_TARGET: StandaloneOSXUniversal

build-StandaloneWindows64:
  <<: *build
  image: $IMAGE:$UNITY_VERSION-windows-mono-$IMAGE_VERSION
  variables:
    BUILD_TARGET: StandaloneWindows64
    TEST: CIAo sono un test

# For webgl support, you need to set Compression Format to Disabled for v0.9. See https://github.com/game-ci/docker/issues/75
#build-WebGL:
#  <<: *build
#  image: $IMAGE:$UNITY_VERSION-webgl-$IMAGE_VERSION
  # Temporary workaround for https://github.com/game-ci/docker/releases/tag/v0.9 and webgl support in current project to prevent errors with missing ffmpeg
#  before_script:
#    - chmod +x ./ci/before_script.sh && ./ci/before_script.sh
#    - apt-get update && apt-get install ffmpeg -y
#  variables:
#    BUILD_TARGET: WebGL

#build-android:
#  <<: *build
#  image: $IMAGE:$UNITY_VERSION-android-$IMAGE_VERSION
#  variables:
#    BUILD_TARGET: Android
#    BUILD_APP_BUNDLE: "false"

#build-android-il2cpp:
#  <<: *build
#  image: $IMAGE:$UNITY_VERSION-android-$IMAGE_VERSION
#  variables:
#    BUILD_TARGET: Android
#    BUILD_APP_BUNDLE: "false"
#    SCRIPTING_BACKEND: IL2CPP

#deploy-android:
#  stage: deploy
#  image: ruby
#  script:
#    - cd $UNITY_DIR/Builds/Android
#    - echo $GPC_TOKEN > gpc_token.json
#    - gem install bundler
#    - bundle install
#    - fastlane supply --aab "${BUILD_NAME}.aab" --track internal --package_name com.youcompany.yourgame --json_key ./gpc_token.json
#  needs: ["build-android"]

#build-ios-xcode:
#  <<: *build
#  image: $IMAGE:$UNITY_VERSION-ios-$IMAGE_VERSION
#  variables:
#    BUILD_TARGET: iOS

#build-and-deploy-ios:
#  stage: deploy
#  script:
#    - cd $UNITY_DIR/Builds/iOS/$BUILD_NAME
#    - pod install
#    - fastlane ios beta
#  tags:
#    - ios
#    - mac
#  needs: ["build-ios-xcode"]

.pages:
  image: alpine:latest
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - mv "$UNITY_DIR/Builds/WebGL/${BUILD_NAME}" public
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
  only:
    - main

workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID
      when: never
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
      when: never
    - when: always
```

Source of the original `.gitlab-ci.yml`:
https://gitlab.com/game-ci/unity3d-gitlab-ci-example/-/blob/main/.gitlab-ci.yml

Comment: Much more context is needed here to give good advice, can you post your CI config as well as git commands or names of tags you're pushing.

Comment: I added the .gitlab-ci.yml. If there is something useful to add let me know it!

Comment: sooo `- if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
      when: never` what do you think this does?

Comment: Aaaah, so this stops the creation for the pipeline for every tag?

Comment: It was that, thank you! I can close the question.